# Error al añadir un fichero a .ZIP

Tags: c#, zip

Al intentar añadir un fichero a un archivo zip me salta este error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

He visto que el fichero .zip se crea, pero el problema viene al intentar añadir un fichero, dice como que no tengo permiso para ir al directorio.
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open("C:\\temp\\temp.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile("C:\\BBDD", "030021.1d_BAK", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
    }
```

Comment: En principio el error es bastante descriptivo. Parece que el usuario con el que ejecutas tu aplicación no tiene permisos de acceso sobre ese archivo. Podria ser tambien que ese archivo ya esté abierto por otro proceso?

Comment: @Pikoh hola, realmente me sorprende este error, ya que el archivo no lo esta utilizando nadie, es mas si hago copy/paste no tengo ningun problema, parece ser que es el programa el que necesita algun tipo de permiso, pero no se cual es y como darselo...

Comment: Para probar si es un tema de permisos, ejecuta to programa como administrador. Si asi te funciona, es tema de permisos

Comment: @pikoh he lanzado el VS 2015 en modo administrador y lo mismo, tambien he lanzado la aplicacion en modo adminstrador y lo mismo, "Access to the path c:\temp is denied"

Comment: Intenta cambiar de carpeta,en lugar de temp usa otra,por ejemplo en tus documentos

Comment: @pikoh si, es lo que he intentado pero igual, estoy un poco atascado... gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ahora que me fijo..creo que estas llamando mal a `CreateEntryFromFile` . Debería ser `archive.CreateEntryFromFile("C:\\BBDD\\030021.1d_BAK", "030021.1d_BAK", CompressionLevel.Fastest);` A no ser que tu archivo sea `BBDD`

Comment: @Pikoh Muchas gracias!, es cierto, no me di cuenta yo tampoco, hay que poner la ruta completa del fichero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método de extensión `CreateEntryFromFile` admite tres parámetros. El primero es la ruta completa del archivo a añadir al zip. En tu caso, parece que estás poniendo una carpeta y no un archivo. Modifica tu código para que sea algo como esto:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open("C:\\temp\\temp.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile("C:\\BBDD\\030021.1d_BAK", "030021.1d_BAK", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
}
```